# Terminal color using terminfo?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ncurses, terminfo

I am writing a C++ class permitting the usage of color in terminal. I want it works on every terminal :

- printing with true color (24 bits) on terminals that supports it,
- with 256 color (6x6x6) on terminals that supports it,
- else with the basic 16 colors.

I wrote once C functions using termcap, and I thought using it in this case. However, the man page says :

> The termcap database is an obsolete facility for describing the capabilities of character-cell terminals and printers. It is retained only for capability with old programs; new ones should use the terminfo database and associated libraries.

So I tried to use terminfo, but I could not find how to do this. There is not terminfo.h in my system (I run on Debian).

My questions is :

How can I get the color possibilities of the current terminal in C/C++, using the newest tools (ie not termcap, according to manpage) ?

Comment: AFAIK, you have to include `curses.h` and `term.h`. You should look for `man tgetent` on your system.

Comment: Are not they termcap functions ?

Comment: Not necessarily on recent systems. [die.net] says for `man getent` *tgetent, tgetflag, tgetnum, tgetstr, tgoto, tputs - direct curses interface to the terminfo capability database*, and so does my FreeBSD 10.1 box.

Comment: Ok : so, I already known that function. But, there is no way to have the truecolor possibility, as far as i can see, with this set of functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you could not get the information from terminfo until *ncurses 6.1* was released in January 2018.

The longer answer:

- to effectively use TrueColor, you need an interface handling 3 parameters (for *red*, *green*, *blue*).  Termcap cannot do this. Terminfo can handle multiple parameters, but...
- there is no standard terminal *capability* (a name for a feature which may be a boolean, number or a string) dealing with TrueColor as such.
- you could adapt existing capabilities, but they have limitations

Looking at the [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual, you might see these (strings):

```
   initialize_color          initc  Ic   initialize color #1
                                         to (#2,#3,#4)
   initialize_pair           initp  Ip   Initialize color
                                         pair #1 to
                                         fg=(#2,#3,#4),
                                         bg=(#5,#6,#7)
```

which are related to these (numbers):

```
   max_colors                colors Co   maximum number of
                                         colors on screen
   max_pairs                 pairs  pa   maximum number of
                                         color-pairs on the
                                         screen
```

ANSI colors and schemes compatible with those (such as 16-, 88- and 256-colors) assume you are coloring foreground and background in *pairs*.  The reason for that was that long ago, hardware terminals just worked that way.  The `initialize_color` capability is for a different scheme (Tektronix), which might seem useful.

However, terminfo is *compiled*, and the resulting binary files stored only signed 16-bit integers.  You could not use the terminal description to store a suitable `max_pairs` *or* `max_colors` for 24-bit color.  (termcap stores everything as strings, but as noted is unsuited for this application).

A couple of years after this question and answer were first written, terminfo was updated to use a new file format that uses signed 32-bit integers, which is enough for expressing the number of colours in 24-bit RGB colour.

More details can be found in release announcement for [ncurses 6.1](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.1.html) and in [the updated `term(5)` manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html#h3-EXTENDED-NUMBER-FORMAT), which latter notes that there are still restrictions in the old API used by some applications that access the terminfo data directly.

Further reading:

- [Why only 16 (or 256) colors?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_16MegaColors) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Can I set a color by its number?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number) (xterm FAQ)
- [Is ncurses terminfo compatible with my system?](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#compatible_tic) (ncurses FAQ)

Comment: >  "signed 16-bit integers."
Is this mentioned anywhere that it stores them in signed 16 bit rather than unsigned. I was hoping to find it somewhere but only search result is this answer for me.

Comment: man [term(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html) refers to "short integers" (if they were unsigned, it would be noted there).